# Ionic and ios9 bugs and issues

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ios9

I have an application with ionic and angularjs, i test the behaviour at ios9 and i'm experiencing a lot of issues and bugs, anyone knows how to solve it?

Greetings

Comment: What kind of "issues and bugs" are you experiencing?

Comment: Scroll block, side menu bad working....Jarek answer helps me a lot, thanks qqilihq

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! As we also have a Ionic app in the works, I wanted to be sure what the issues might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this patch:

[angular-ios9-uiwebview.patch.js](https://gist.github.com/IgorMinar/863acd413e3925bf282c)

Comment: Can you elaborate more? This is too small answer with only a link.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer - Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: This Ionic blog post explains the problem and the solution:  http://blog.ionic.io/ios-9-potential-breaking-change/

Comment: Thank you Jarek, is very usefull that patch for me!!